# Java 8 Lambda Chaining - Type Safety Enforcement

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Snippet 1:

```
Optional.of(s).map(str -> str).orElse("");
```

Snippet 2:

```
Optional.of(s).map(str -> str).orElse(Optional.empty());
```

Snippet 3:

```
Optional.of(s).map(str -> Optional.of(str)).orElse("hello");
```

`Snippet 1` is compiling fine but `Snippet 2` & `Snippet 3` compile with type incompatibility errors. While it's good that `Snippet 2` & `Snippet 3` fail, I do not understand how they are evaluated. In other words, I think I am missing some basics in terms of how the lambdas themselves are chained/invoked. Would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with lambdas or complex type inference. It's just about arguments of the wrong type.

Comment: @ernest_k yeah - wasn't looking at the javadocs closely enough. The type safety appears to be stemming from the use of generics in the `Optional` class on both `map` and `orElse`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Snippet 1:

```
Optional.of(s).map(str -> str).orElse("");
```

Compiles because the default value provided to [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) *is the same type as the value the `Optional` contains* i.e. a `String`.

Snippet 2:

```
Optional.of(s).map(str -> str).orElse(Optional.empty());
```

does not compile because after `map` you have a `Optional<String>` but then you're providing a `Optional<String>` in the `orElse` whereas it should be a `String`.

Snippet 3:

```
Optional.of(s).map(str -> Optional.of(str)).orElse("hello");
```

does not compile because after `map` you have a `Optional<Optional<String>>` but you're passing a `String` in the `orElse` whereas it should be a `Optional<String>`.

To conclude `orElse` is declared as:

> public T orElse(T other)

and documented as:

> Returns the value if present, otherwise return other.

i.e. `orElse` basically says "give me the value the optional contains if present otherwise take the default value" as well as that `T` must be the same type as the value the `Optional` contains.

so if you have a `Optional<String` then you must supply a `String` to  `orElse`, if you have a `Optional<Integer` then you must supply a `Integer` to  `orElse` etc...

---

On another note, the `map` function in your first and second example snippets are superfluous and you can, therefore, omit it completely.

Whenever you see your self calling `Optional#map` with the function as `v -> v` it's probably not needed.

Comment: It’s worth noting that due to the fact that the `map` invocation is in the middle of a chain, only the left-hand side is considered by the type inference, as otherwise, we could infer different function types to make it work. E.g., you can make all examples work by replacing `.map(…)` with `.<Object>map(…)`.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking down Snippet 2:

```
Optional.of(s)            //Optional<String>
        .map(str -> str)  //Optional<String>
        .orElse(Optional.empty()); //String or Optional<String>?
```

And Snippet 3:

```
Optional.of(s)                        //Optional<String>
        .map(str -> Optional.of(str)) //Optional<Optional<String>>
        .orElse("hello");             //Optional<String> or String?
```

Now, for Snippet 3, using `flatMap` can be used to get rid of the nested optionals:

```
Optional.of(s)                            //Optional<String>
        .flatMap(str -> Optional.of(str)) //Optional<String>
        .orElse("hello");                 //String
```

Comment: Using jdk9+, `.flatMap(str -> Optional.of(str))` can be replaced with `.or(() -> Optional.of(str))` (probably a minor improvement)

Answer (score 3):

`.orElse()` attempts to repackage the `Optional`, and if nothing is found, provide a default value, hence the object passed to `.orElse()` needs to be compatible with what Optional is holding at the moment.

In other words, if you have an `Optional<T>`, you need to pass `T` to the `orElse()` method.

In this case, you start with `Optional<String` and then you derive `Optional<Optional<String>>` from it:

`Optional.of(s)
     .map(str -> Optional.of(str))
     .orElse("hello");`

If you pass `str -> str` to the `map(...)`, it will compile.

Answer (score 1):

The type returned by `map` is (e.g. seen by hovering over `map` in Eclipse):

1. `Optional<String>`
2. `Optional<String>`
3. `Optional<Optional<String>>`

[`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) is defined as `public T orElse(T other)` which means that the parameter must be a `T`, so:

1. `orElse("")` ― `""` is correctly a `String`
2. `orElse(Optional.empty())` ― `Optional<?>` is not a `String`
3. `orElse("hello")` ― `"hello"` is not an `Optional<String>`

Answer (score 1):

The signature of `orElse` is : `public T orElse(T other)`.
It should return the same type as the content of the `Optional<T>`.
In your second case what would you assign the type to the return value, `String` or  `Optional<String>`?

```
??? value = Optional.of(s).map(str -> str).orElse(Optional.empty());
```

In the third case you are doing the exactly opposite.
The actual content is now `Optional<String>` and the `orElse` is returning `String`.

Hope this helps.